# I want SPACE+Mbutton to send another button without stopping space function

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

I  want my script to send another button when I press both spacebar and middle mouse button. However, I also want the spacebar to work normally when only space is pressed (i.e. it makes spaces as normal).

I've tried the script below and "space + middle mouse button" does send 9, but space doesn't work when only space is pressed (it doesn't make spaces).

```
SPACE & MButton:: Send 9
```

Answer (score 1):

This two sentences together do the job pretty well:

```
 Space & MButton::Send 9
 Space::Send, {SPACE}
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can preserve a key's functionality with the `~` [hotkey modifier](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols)**

> When the hotkey fires, its key's native function will not be blocked
>   (hidden from the system).

So to preserve the spacebar's functionality, your hotkey would be:

```
~Space & MButton::Send 9
```